Google Firebase Storage Rules prevent sending file upload from Next.JS endpoint
Context: I have a web app built in Next.JS using Firebase Storage for file storage. I am successfully able to upload files when I have removed Firebase rules/set Firebase rules to public. I need to implement stronger rules to protect the DB.
I am not using Firebase authentication, I am using NextAuth. The use case requires the metadata to be checked against users and organisation in Firestore (firestore.get() / firestore.exists()).
I have tried some baseline rules and the below rules work, I am able to successfully upload files:
// Allow anyone to read/write - PUBLIC
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

// Allow anyone to read/write if there is a request
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request != null;
    }
  }
}

Problem: When trying to implement any other rules the upload fails with:

status 403 - Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access

The problem seems to stem from the request.resource is always undefined (I can see this when I console log in my code). This is very confusing as when the rules are removed/made public, the file uploads successfully which tells me that the request.resource is not undefined. Further adding to my confusion, when I have uploaded files with laxed rules I can see in the files metadata that the fields are definitely there:

When testing the below rule in Firebase rules playground it works as expected, but when publishing the rule and trigger the endpoint, it fails with the above error:
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.resource.metadata != null;
    }
  }
}

Backend code:
imports...


export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disable Next.js's default body parser
  },
};

export interface ParsedForm {
  fields: formidable.Fields;
  files: formidable.Files;
}

// Helper function to initialize formidable and parse form data
const parseForm = (req: IncomingMessage): Promise<ParsedForm> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true, keepExtensions: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions(req, res));

  if (!session || !session.user) {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Unauthorized' });
    return;
  }

  const user = session.user as User;
  const { method } = req;

  if (method !== 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
    return;
  }

  try {
    const { fields, files } = await parseForm(req);

    // Ensure `file` is an array and access the first element
    const fileArray = files.file;
    if (!fileArray || !Array.isArray(fileArray) || fileArray.length === 0) {
      res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'No file provided' });
      return;
    }

    const metaData = {
      contentType: fileArray[0].mimetype || 'application/octet-stream',
      customMetadata: {
        userId: user.id,
        organisationId: user.organisationID,
      },
    };

    const file = fileArray[0];
    const currentDateTimeSinceEpoch = secondsSinceEpoch();

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `uploads/${user.organisationID}/${currentDateTimeSinceEpoch}_${file.originalFilename}`);

    // Read the file as a buffer
    const fileBuffer = await fs.readFile(file.filepath);

    // Upload the file to Firebase Storage
    const uploadResult = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fileBuffer, metaData);
    console.log(" ~ handler ~ uploadResult:", uploadResult)

    // Get the download URL
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

    // Optionally, remove the file from the local filesystem after uploading
    await fs.unlink(file.filepath);

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, url: downloadURL });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to upload file:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to upload file' });
  }
}


Solved
The issue/error I was facing came down to multiple things but in summary I was using a mix of v9 and v10 Firebase, as well as using Firebase (client side) on the server instead of using Firebase-admin (SDK), causing some strange behaviour.
When using v10 Firebase, ensure you are using the correct imports and functions if you initialized your app with Firebase-admin. Also, make sure that you are using the correct libraries/SDK imports.
The below fixed my issues and I did not need the rules at all having set up the Firebase-admin SDK properly:
import { getStorage } from "firebase-admin/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET);
const fileRef = bucket.file(`uploads/${user.organisationID}/${file.originalFilename}`);
await fileRef.save(fileData, metaData);

The below was how I was previously doing it and causing errors:
import { storage } from '@/config/firebase';
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage"; //This is actually the client side SDK

const storageRef = ref(storage, `uploads/${user.organisationID}/${currentDateTimeSinceEpoch}_${file.originalFilename}`); 

